# Ruby Array Object with named index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I am trying to create an ruby array so that i can hold some data and create that into a JSON object to store into the DATABASE.

```
browser_meta = Array.new
        browser_meta.name = browser.name;
        browser_meta.version = browser.full_version;
        browser_meta.platform = browser.platform;
        browser_meta.name = browser.name;
        browser_meta.name = browser.name;
```

**Error:**

```
undefined method `name=' for []:Array
```

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make any sense at all. You are completely misusing `Array`.

Comment: What tutorial told you that you could do that to an Array?  Here is a list of Array methods: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html. Do you see a method named `name=` in the list?   Go study up on ruby Hashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array is a bad choice for key value data structure.
Use hash instead:

```
browser_meta = { name: browser.name, version: browser.full_version .....}
```

Then you can covert it to json with

```
require 'json'
browser_meta_json = browser_meta.to_json
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to be able to access the values using the dot notation:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html

```
require 'ostruct'

person = OpenStruct.new
person.name    = "John Smith"
person.age     = 70
person.pension = 300

puts person.name     # -> "John Smith"
puts person.age      # -> 70
puts person.address  # -> nil
```